# Apply CSS changes via jQuery after going back in browser

Tags: jquery, css

I have a DIV with a green background. No I use jQuery to change the background to red:

```
$('div').css('background-color','red');
```

Now, if a go in my browser to some other page and then use the "Go Back" function of the browser to go back to the page with my div, the div is green again.

Is there an easy way of keeping the CSS change in the browser history, so that if I go back the div is still red?

Comment: Do you have this code inside of a dom event?

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand your question. The JS code is at the bottom of my html document.

Comment: You would need to store the change somewhere, like in a cookie, session, localstorage, etc. and read it back every time the page is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that you're changing the color based on user action, or else it would just be red by default. So, you can simply store the color in a cookie.

I like this option, it's easy to set/store/destroy cookies: https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

Then, just set the cookie `$.cookie("color", value);`

When you come back to the page, you can see if you have a stored value for the color by retrieving the cookie: `var divColor = $.cookie("color");`

I'd also recommend to set the color with classes. Maybe a class `.red` and `.green` so on...I find it better to separate it like that.